# SSH from Local Computer through a Bastion to Internal Git Server

Tags: git, ssh

I'm wondering if this is possible. I need to be able to reach an internal only GIT server through a bastion but I cannot edit the config of my local computer. Ideally I would like to be able to run something like "git clone ssh://bastion ip internal git ip/home/git.test".

A lot of the questions on Stack and other places indicate that the best way to achieve something like this is to modify your local computer's config to do the proxy jump. Is there a way to setup the bastion to do this instead so that if I connect to the bastion's IP maybe it would auto-go to the git server instead?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be *something like* `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -J bastion_ip" git clone ssh://internal_ip/home/git.test` To test if the internal host is accessible via ssh without git try `ssh -J bastion_ip internal_ip`

Comment: That *is* the *best* way (for some measure of best) because it's persistent (that's the measure of best firing here). The `-J` trick that @phd mentions should work fine.